# publish / build angular 5 app without CLI

Tags: angular, build, publish

I know **ngBuild** works good for Building angular 5 app which uses CLI. but i have Angular 5 app with out CLI, i want to know how to build this application to publish in IIS.

Comment: are you using `webpack`?

Comment: Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try providing more explanation about your question.

Comment: @Vikas No i am using _**gulp**_

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution. My Angular App was **without CLI** so i could not use ***ngBuild***.
But my application was using ***gulp***. Feature of gulp is whenever you run command ***npm start*** to run your App it builds your application. So to host your application in IIS you just have to place your **application folder** in IIS Hosting website's physical path.